# AUC with incomplete ROC curve

Tags: roc, auc

I am doing an experiments where changing a parameter I am obtaining different number of FalsePositive, FalseNegative... and so on.
I am using this parameter tuning as threshold tuning to obtain FPR and TPR to build a ROC curve.
However, the problem is so easy tha it gets most of the time the point near [1,0]. I never have any point near [1,1]. If I want to compute the AUC, what am I supposed to do? To add artificially a point [1,1]?

Moreover, for another experiment I have some values of TPR and FPR which are disproportionated to other cases, and they look weird.

Thank you.
Best,[image]

---

Thank you. Now I am using directly probabilities from the classifier. However, I am still not getting to the point [1,1].

Comment: It's fine to add points at (0,0) and (1,1) to a ROC curve, but what you have here cannot be a ROC curve  because ROC curves are defined to be non-decreasing!

Comment: @sycorax missing those points means that you are missing thresholds. In my experience it is usually indicative of a problem deeper than those two points.

Comment: @Alex how are you getting your thresholds? Are you for instance taking random points in the interval (0,1)?

Comment: @Calimo We're saying the same thing. If the max and min prediction values on some data set are 0.9 and 0.1, then the ROC points (0,0) and (1,1) are generated by appending predictions smaller and larger than 0.1 and 0.9, resp. and then proceeding as usual with cumulative sums or whatnot. Another way to look at this is that a ROC curve is characterized as a nondecreasing curve from (0,0) to (1,1), so appending (0,0) and (1,1) has no significance beyond satisfying this quality.

Answer (score 3):

To create a ROC curve, you need to vary the **decision threshold** of a single classifier, not the parameters of the model itself.

I recommend Tom Fawcett's "[An Introduction to ROC Analysis](http://people.inf.elte.hu/kiss/11dwhdm/roc.pdf)" to get started with ROC analysis. He gives an algorithm to correctly build the full ROC curve that always contains all thresholds, including (0,0) and (1,1) (see Algorithm 1, p. 866).

Comment: Thank you. Now I am using directly probabilities from the classifier. However, I am still not getting to the point [1,1].

Comment: @alex you should have posted a new question, this one is completely different. But really you should read Fawcett's paper. Algorithm 1 gives you a curve that always contains (1,1). I edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

If Calimo's answer has helped you generate a legitimate ROC curve, it's OK to manually add a point at (0, 0) or (1, 1) if you're trying to calculate the AUC by summing up the areas of rectangles.

Note that there are other interpretations of AUC that don't invoke the ROC curve at all, e.g. a concordance measure. See [the accepted answere here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145566/how-to-calculate-area-under-the-curve-auc-or-the-c-statistic-by-hand) for more detail.

Finally, I think your original question might be reflecting a misunderstanding of how the ROC curve is constructed; in addition to Tom Fawcett's paper that Calimo linked to, a while ago I put together a visual introduction that you or other visitors might find helpful:

https://callumwebby.com/portfolio/ROC/

I haven't got around to discussing AUC, but it includes some example code that might help understanding. You'll see that I manually add a point at (0, 0) just so the endpoints span the full space.

Comment: The absence of (1,1) indicates that he is still *not* doing a ROC curve. A good algorithm such as the one described by Fawcett gives you that point consistently 100% of the time.

Comment: Having one of the endpoints missing can easily just be a result of only plotting points in the ROC space for the n predictions when you really need n + 1. It doesn't invalidate the rest of the curve.

The algorithm described by Fawcett avoids this by creating a point at (0, 0) before considering the predictions, similar to my cumulative sum approach which appends a pair of zeros to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks to me like, as you say, your task is far to easy and you are achieving a really high d' with maybe a change in variance. However, it is hard to say unless you actually fit an unequal-variant SDT model to your empirical data. Honestly, you are probably never going to get enough power in your experiment to go to [1,1]. You really should reduce the level of discriminability between your target and noise stimuli to remove the ceiling effect. I really can't see anything wrong with calculating AUC from what you have already. But you should really adjust your stimuli (e.g. make your noise stimuli more similar to the target stimuli - or degrade the target stimuli) and redo the experiment. You should notice a reduction in AUC and the data reaching a perfect detection further towards [1,1].

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.