# ROC curve interpretation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, roc, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, precision-recall

In the context of binary classification how do you interpret ROC curve: more precisely:

1) Why the diagonal stand for a random classifier?

[Edit] Let's imagine a random classifier: each time he see an observation he labels this observation to 1 with a probability of 0.5.

So with a lot of observations,

- among the observation with true label 1 half of them will be correctly classified.
- In the same way there is a 0.5 false positive rate (among the true label 0 half of them will be classified 1).

So on ROC curve this classifier will be on the diagonal on the point (0.5,0.5). But I can only see this case unless i don't understand well the meaning of random classifier in this context...

2) Why ROC curve is insensitive to Class skew ? Why ROC curve is insensitive to  class distributions or error costs.

Let's imagine we have a sample of observation and we draw the ROC curve. Now let's add a lot of observation wich are labelled 0, does the ROC curve stay the same ? what does it mean and how to explain this ?

Her I saw an explanation: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-AUC-Area-under-ROC-insensitive-to-class-distribution-changes; the answers seems good if we assume that when we increase the number of negative sample they should be distributed with the same score distribution that the previous neagative samples.

---

PS: A mathematical paper (with proof) could help me to well understand the previous assertion since it will be formally defined. I found this one (in my language) but i am not sur it is correct since there seem to have a mistake since the begining with the RECALL definition: http://www.xavierdupre.fr/app/mlstatpy/helpsphinx/c_metric/roc.html.  So if you have any reference please share it. I

Comment: Have you reviewed the answers on this thread? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145566/how-to-calculate-area-under-the-curve-auc-or-the-c-statistic-by-hand The explanation for why the diagonal corresponds to the random classifier derives from the connection to the Wilxcoxon-Mann-Whitney test. If this link doesn't help you, please edit your question to clarify what you don't understand & we can help you get unstuck.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful link! I understand the interpretation with the concordance. So if each 0 and each 1 is mapped to a random score i understand that AUC is 0.5 since we can draw half proportion of line with positive slope. But i still don' t get the ROC curve. Why the diagonal? There could be an infinite numbers of path whose area is 0.5 !