# Area under the curve score training/validation set

Tags: machine-learning, roc

Lets say I have a very basic, binary classification problem and I use logistic regression. 
The logistic regression will give me a score (not a classification yet), between 0 and 1.

I can use sklearn's `roc_auc_score` to calculate the ROC easily by using `roc_auc_score(y_train, predicted_scores)`. The function will find the best threshold for me.

However, if I want to check the ROC for my validation set, can I just use `roc_auc_score(y_val, predicted_val_scores)`? Because then it will look again for the best threshold right? Should I not find a way to use the same threshold as in the first function? Or am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write

> I can use sklearn's roc_auc_score to calculate the ROC easily by using roc_auc_score(y_train, predicted_scores). The function will find the best threshold for me.

but `roc_auc_score` doesn't find the best threshold, it just measures the area under the ROC curve. Finding the area under the ROC curve doesn't involve finding a single, "best" threshold. See [How to calculate Area Under the Curve (AUC), or the c-statistic, by hand](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145566/how-to-calculate-area-under-the-curve-auc-or-the-c-statistic-by-hand) for an explanation of how this works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And the of course the area under the curve does not have to do anything with a threshold, but to draw the ROC curve, you need to specifiy several cut-offs (as is stated in the thread you linked). I mean, predicted_scores needs to be converted to a binary classification outcome to calculate the sensitivity/specificity/tpf etc, and apparently roc_auc_score does this for me, since I only specify the predicted probabilities and the true Y (which is binary)

Comment: Yes, your comment is an accurate summary of how this function works.

Comment: Then again, when I run the roc_auc_score function, it converts the probabilities to a binary prediction and uses a cutoff for this. Shouldnt I use the cutoff roc_auc_score uses on the training data on the validation set as well? 
Because right now I am just calling the function twice (once on training set, once on validation set) but Im not sure if I am allowed, since it can use a different cutoff when called on the validation set, which does not seem fair. Hope this is clear?

Comment: The cutoffs depend on the data alone, so you’re fine. In other words, the AUC is a statistic based on ranks, and we can always rank probabilities without having to refer to another data set. You’re correct to worry about out-of-sample properties, but that’s actually captured by estimating the error of the AUC. AUC is a statistic, so it has an associated error.