# Least square for binary classification {0, 1}: is the threshold always equal to 0.5?

Tags: classification, linear, threshold

When using least square for classification of two classes labeled as 0 and 1, the value 0.5 is a common choice for the threshold.

Intuitively, it makes sense, but is it always optimal? In which sense?

Comment: You might want to look into the “proper scoring rules” that get talked about on here sometimes. I also like Frank Harrell’s blog: https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/ https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/

Comment: Some relevant discussions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312780/why-is-accuracy-not-the-best-measure-for-assessing-classification-models and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105501/understanding-roc-curve/105577#105577

Comment: [Here is a previous thread on thresholds.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352)

Comment: See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123124/how-to-determine-the-optimal-threshold-for-a-classifier-and-generate-roc-curve